# How to use aggregation single query for array and array in side array for get details from mongodb ?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I want to use aggregation query in three table on mongodb, 
I listed three table that store db data, and i send you query that i used, 
but output not getting that i want.

**Order Table**

In Order Table I have one create order and in that Object "Order Details"

```
"order_details":[

{
    "product_unique_id" : 10
    "items":[
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 1
        "quantity":2,
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 2
        "quantity":4,
    }
    ]
},
{
    "product_unique_id" : 11
    "items":[
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 1
        "quantity":1,
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 3
        "quantity":3,
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 4 
        "quantity":2,
    }
    ]
}
]
```

**Product Table**

```
Data 1 =>  {"unique_id":10, "product_name":"Product10", "product_visible":true}
Data 2 =>  {"unique_id":11, "product_name":"Product11", "product_visible":false}
Data 3 =>  {"unique_id":12, "product_name":"Product13", "product_visible":true}
... up to N
```

**Item Table**

```
Data 1 =>  {"unique_id":1, "item_name":"Item1", "price":17}
Data 2 =>  {"unique_id":2, "item_name":"Item2", "price":9}
Data 3 =>  {"unique_id":3, "item_name":"Item3", "price":34}
Data 4 =>  {"unique_id":4, "item_name":"Item4", "price":78}
Data 5 =>  {"unique_id":5, "item_name":"Item5", "price":26}
```

I want to run aggregation query in order table and want response as below

***OUTPUT I WANT IS***

```
"order_details":[
{
    "product_unique_id" : 10,
    "product_detail": {"unique_id":10, "product_name":"Product10", "product_visible":true},
    "items":[
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 1
        "quantity":2,
        "item_details":{"unique_id":1, "item_name":"Item1", "price":17}
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 2
        "quantity":4,
        "item_details":{"unique_id":2, "item_name":"Item2", "price":9}
    }
    ]
},
{
    "product_unique_id" : 11,
    "product_detail": {"unique_id":11, "product_name":"Product11", "product_visible":false},
    "items":[
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 1
        "quantity":1,
        "item_details":{"unique_id":1, "item_name":"Item1", "price":17}
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 3
        "quantity":3,
        "item_details":{"unique_id":3, "item_name":"Item3", "price":34}
    },
    {
        "item_unique_id" : 4 
        "quantity":2,
        "item_details":{"unique_id":4, "item_name":"Item4", "price":78}
    }
    ]
}
]
```

*I USED SOME QUERY FOR THAT BUT OUT PUT COMING WITH MULTIPLE ITEMS*

```
var product_query = {
    $lookup:
        {
        from: "products",
        localField: "order_details.product_unique_id",
        foreignField: "unique_id",
        as: "order_details.product_detail"
        }
};


var group_product = {
    $group: {
        _id: '$order_details'
    }
}

var item_query = {
    $lookup:
        {
        from: "items",
        localField: "order_details.items.item_unique_id",
        foreignField: "unique_id",
        as: "order_details.item_details"
        }
};

Order.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$order_details"},
    {$unwind: "$order_details.items"},
    product_query,
    item_query,
    group_product

], function (error, order) {
    // OUT PUT HERE
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation pipeline. I'm assuming you are on 3.2 version.

Pretty standard stuff. You'll need to `$unwind + $lookup +  $group` couple of times each for `items` and `products` and rest is formatting the response to put everything back into the original structure.

```
db.orders.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$order_details"},
    {$unwind: "$order_details.items"},
    {$lookup:{
        from: "items",
        localField: "order_details.items.item_unique_id",
        foreignField: "unique_id",
        as: "order_details.items.item_details"
      }
    },
    {$unwind: "$order_details.items.item_details"},
    { $group: {
        _id: {order_id:'$_id', product_unique_id:"$order_details.product_unique_id"}, 
        "items": {$push:"$order_details.items"}
        }
    },
    {$lookup:{
        from: "products",
        localField: "_id.product_unique_id",
        foreignField: "unique_id",
        as: "_id.product_detail"
      }
    },
    {$unwind: "$_id.product_detail"},
    {$project:{
        "order_detail.product_unique_id":"$_id.product_unique_id",
        "order_detail.product_detail":"$_id.product_detail", 
        "order_detail.items":"$items"  
        }
    },
    {$group: {
        _id: '$_id.order_id', order_details:{$push:"$order_detail"}
        }
    }
])
```

This pipeline can further be improved for 3.4 version. I can add extra edits if you need for 3.4 version.

Comment: thanks for your information, 
It's work for me. Awesome.

Please can you share pipeline query if you have.

Comment: You are welcome. Do you mean pipeline query for 3.4 version ?